# excel 2007, assign value in column C where column A matches column B

Tags: excel-2007

I have an excel worksheet with columns A, B, C...columns A and B have some matching values. Column B and C are grouped together meaning the cells correspond to each other and now I want to assign whatever is in C where A matches B. I hope this makes sense. I could do it in sql i guess but i do not want to export all the data.

for example

```
Column B                             
http://alabama.scout.com
http://www.netmag.co.uk
http://dotnet.sys-con.com


Column C
UNITED STATES
UNITED KINGDOM
UNITED STATES


Column A
http://www.1tv.ru
http://alabama.scout.com
http://www.01net.com
http://www.ten-tenths.com

Column D
```

Ok so i need to insert in column D where A = B the value of C. Sorry just to be more clear column B values are assigned with column C values, so subsequently column A will be assigned with column D

Comment: So it's something like this? :
Column A - 45,67,23
Column B - 16,67,88
Column C - 09,72,87
And you want the 67s to be replaced by 72 now? Is that what you mean?

Comment: not exactly, i want to add the column C (value 72) where col A( 67) in a column adjacent to it and not replace column A...thanks for the response

Comment: So A should become 45,135,88? And B too? Pls clarify or give an example.

Comment: please see edit, appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
 =VLOOKUP(A3,$B$2:$C$4,2,FALSE)
```

Answer (score -1):

=IF(A1=B1, "True", "False")

Comment: so for true how would i insert C value into D